# Unable check auth with in same page in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

This is my first laravel project. I am making a website with login user.I question is when i enter my url then open always home page.If user logged in then it show name in navbar and for guest always show as a guest.I don't want to change url for both case....Even when a guest after login it goes to same url but then that user show as a auth user. Please help me How can I do that. I take concept from ecommerce website.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'WebController@loadPage');
    Route::get('/signin', 'WebController@login');
});
```

this is my route.I already change navbar using @auth and @guest.But how to check at first that the user r auth or not without changing url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware for authenticated routes.
if you using default `auth` of laravel then simply set route middleware for your authenticated routes like below

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function (){
 //Your Protected routes goes here
});
```

or if you want to redirect your user to some custom route after login then simple you can edit this in `LoginCOntroller` inside `Controller/Auth` and set varibale `protected $redirectTo = '/YourRedirectionPath';`

I suggest you read the documentation it is well documented [Authentication documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)

Comment: In want to when user hit url then goes to home page.I tried your answer. it shows 404 error page not found.please give me more details.

Comment: 404 error page on which url can you comment where it redirecting